# Web scraping with pagination in Python - how to add rows to a DataFrame in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script that scrapes data from a site with school information. The 'search' page being scraped has school districts in a drop-down box. The script loops through all districts and extracts data from the page of each district, which has multiple schools, with some districts having schools across several pages.

I would like to add all of the schools to a DataFrame and then write the data to a file.

However, I get the following error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 87 elements, new values have 2 elements`.

Here is the code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

districts = "https://web36.gov.mb.ca/school/school?action=district"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(districts).content, "html.parser")

options = soup.find("select",{"name":"DivisionSelection"}).findAll("option")

name = [option.get_text(strip=True) for option in options[1:]]

id_ = [option.get('value') for option in options[1:]]
id_.pop(1)
id_.pop(4)

mylist = []
for i in id_:
    search_page = f"https://web36.gov.mb.ca/school/school?action=district&DivisionSelection={i}"
    request = requests.get(search_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
    n_schools = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'n_schools'})
    n_schools= re.findall("[0-9]+",str(n_schools))
    High=n_schools[2]
    schools = f"https://web36.gov.mb.ca/school/school?action=district&High={High}&Low=1&DivisionSelection={i}"
    request = requests.get(schools)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")

    data = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'sc_address'})

    data = [[x.get_text(separator="<br>", strip=True) for x in y.findAll('div')] for y in data]
    mylist.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist[1:])
headerName=['Name', 'Info']
df.columns=headerName

df['Address'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 1, expand=True)[0]
df['City'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 2, expand=True)[1]
df['Postal Code'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 3, expand=True)[2]
df['Phone'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 5, expand=True)[4]
df['Fax'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 7, expand=True)[6]
df['Grades'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 9, expand=True)[8]
df['Program'] = df['Info'].str.split("<br>", n = 11, expand=True)[10]

df = df.drop('Info', axis=1)

df.to_csv("output.tsv", sep = "\t",index=False)
```

Comment: You're replacing the `data` in each iteration with new list. Try to append to `data` (initialize `data` to empty list before the for-loop)

Comment: I tried that. I initialized an empty list `mylist` before the for loop and then I added this at the very end of the for loop: `mylist.append(data)`. But it's still only giving me schools from just one district.

Comment: You have to create the final dataframe from `mylist`: `df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)`, not from `data`

Comment: I get the following error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 87 elements, new values have 2 elements`. Is `.append()` adding all of the districts as columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        params = {
            'action': 'district'
        }
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        opts = [(x['value'], x.text) for x in soup.select(
            "select[name='DivisionSelection'] > option:not(:first-child)")]
        allin = []
        for sc in opts:
            data = {
                'DivisionSelection': sc[0],
                'SchoolsInDistrict': 'submit'
            }
            r = req.post(
                'https://web36.gov.mb.ca/school/school?action=district', data=data)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            max = soup.select_one('.n_schools strong')
            if max:
                mx = max.text.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1]
                params = {
                    'High': mx,
                    'Low': '1',
                    'DivisionSelection': sc[0],
                    'action': 'district'
                }
                r = req.get(url, params=params)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
                goal = soup.select('div.sc_address:not(:first-child)')
                if goal:
                    print(sc[1])
                    target = [[sc[1], *x.stripped_strings] for x in goal]
                    for x in target:
                        del x[5::2]
                    allin.extend(target)

        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://web36.gov.mb.ca/school/school')
```

Output:

```
                            0  ...                                                  8      
0      Adult Learning Centres  ...                                            English      
1      Adult Learning Centres  ...                                            English      
2      Adult Learning Centres  ...                                            English      
3      Adult Learning Centres  ...                                            English      
4      Adult Learning Centres  ...                                            English      
..                        ...  ...                                                ...      
960  Winnipeg School Division  ...                                    Early Immersion      
961  Winnipeg School Division  ...  Early Immersion, English, French: Communicatio...      
962  Winnipeg School Division  ...                           Early Immersion, English      
963  Winnipeg School Division  ...                                    Early Immersion      
964  Winnipeg School Division  ...                           Early Immersion, English      

[965 rows x 9 columns]
```

> You can use df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)